# box2d contact listener fixtures order

Tags: java, box2d

I am trying to understand how does it work.

In my game I use box2d physics, to handle contacts I use contact listener, example:

```
ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
{
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact)
    {
        final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
        final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB(); 

        if (x1.getBody().getUserData() != null && x2.getBody().getUserData() != null)
        {                   
            if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("player"))
            {                                               
                player.increaseFootContacts();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here`s question, is there any order in those fixtures? (x1 or x2) after 2 test, I found out that in this case, my player will be x1, and other objects x2, should I also check reverse order ? (if x2 is player and so on) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee which fixture is which. You have to check for both possibilities, like this:

```
if ( (userdataA.equals("player") && userDataB.equals("ground")) ||
     (userdataA.equals("ground") && userDataB.equals("player")) )
         player.increaseFootContacts();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, that`s why I am bit confused now, from what you say I can conclude that my way supposed to not work at all sometimes (50% chance I would say) Because I just logged which fixture will be my player, and latter used it with single check, and somehow it worked ... always (Well I was testing my game on approx. 20 devices, [android] and hundreds of test on my own device while development) Do you think there would be noticeable performance impact for this additional check? Assuming that on my contact listener I compare about 15 different objects, to execute different actions.Thanks

Comment: In practice, you can make an educated guess about which fixture is which, mainly based on the order that you created things in the world. If you create everything exactly the same you will get the same results, on any device etc. but it's not a good idea to rely on that kind of assumption. About optimization, I would first point out that if it's not actually a performance problem, don't touch it :) I think the best way to improve speed here would be to replace the string user data with an integer or enum value which is faster to compare.

Comment: Thank you, so for now I will stay with "educated guess". Also I have been thinking about improving code in contact listener, as you said by replacing it by for example int. For now I do not have performance issues, even on older devices (approx. 57 fps) but I believe its always good to have some places where we can improve performance a bit.

Comment: I see. Remember this code is only called when two things touch anyway :)